# android direction api getting exact maneuver that should be displayed

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, google-directions-api

My app should draw the route from current location of device to the destination i want,

until now there is no problem, and my app can draw this route by decoding the coordinates in the json file.
what i want is the maneuver information in the json file,
as you know there is one maneuver information for each step in the route.
so when i am driving i want to show the exact maneuver information when i reach to the end of each step.
what i mean is how to know which maneuver should be showing to the user?
should i take the current location of the user and determine if the user is around the coordinate of the start of the other step? then show maneuver of that step?
or is there some other magical method that takes json file and return the exact maneuver information when the user reaches to the end of each step?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the maneuver element contained in the json response? You should probably create an icon for each possible maneuver value defined by Google and then use the maneuver element to decide which icon to display.  See the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) for all the possible values.